# How to design a dynamic table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I am building a project about **Recruitment platform**, it includes a lot of types of work.

Each type of work contains multiple form fields, these fields could be text input, radio, checkbox, drop down list or cascading options(if select one option, the another option will be shown) etc.

As resume and position, both of them have it's own type of work(one-to-one), but also contains difference form fields.

And that some of these form field could be used to filter resumes or positions.

It is too hard for me to design these tables. 
I need some prompts or documentations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do dynamic tables in a RDBMS can be achieved through the EAV principle.
You have a table which includes all `attributes` which defines which attributes exists and what they types are.

Than you have a second table(s) which includes all values. Most of the time you create for each type a separate table to use the RDBMS types. For example `eav_attribute_datetime` or `eav_attribute_varchar`.

But be aware this, if you use this pattern you will hit on someday a performance bottenleck. Than you should use flat tables.

An other option is to use a NoSQL database or [MariaDB Dynamic Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/) feature. 
But i didn't use this feature, so i can give you insights about it.

I hope this will answer you questions.